# Pass variable to one page and find in the combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, combobox

I am doing a HTML page with employee leave details. In that page, pending leave option having edit option. User may have edit that leave while its in PENDING. Once I click the edit button, the correspond row details will pass to update page. Leave type should be an combo box. So how to pass that combobox and make that variable as selected.

For example, When i click the edit button in Casual Leave category, the output should be

```
<select id="select_type">
    <option value="Earned Leave">Earned Leave</option>
    <option value="Casual Leave" selected>Casual Leave</option>
</select>
```

P.S: Need to pass the variable via javascript
So my javascript to pass the variable as below

```
function GetUrlValue(VarSearch){
var SearchString = window.location.search.substring(1);
var VariableArray = SearchString.split('&');
for(var i = 0; i < VariableArray.length; i++){
    var KeyValuePair = VariableArray[i].split('=');
    if(KeyValuePair[0] == VarSearch){
        return KeyValuePair[1];
    }
}
}
var x = decodeURIComponent(GetUrlValue('ReqType'));
var y = decodeURIComponent(GetUrlValue('FromDate'));
var z = decodeURIComponent(GetUrlValue('ToDate'));
var z1 = decodeURIComponent(GetUrlValue('NoDays'));
```

So pass the value to the combo box text and make it as selected. Hope you got my point.

Comment: There is many ways to do it. For eg. you can store that data in session, local storage, global variables etc.

Comment: i got all the value. but i need to find the combo box text and make it as selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it like this, if you have the option value

```
var yourSelectedValue = somevalue;

$('#select_type option[value='+yourSelectedValue +']').attr('selected','selected');
```

Or like this

```
$("#select_type").val(yourSelectedValue );
```

Comment: i don want to pass static variable. Need to pass dynamic variable. Consider, if i click to edit the row which contains Privilege Leave???

Comment: You will pass the value and then assign it to the option field as selected.